# Infinite Rubinstein bargaining game

Tags: game-theory

I come across a question:

> Player 1 and Player 2 are to split \$1 in a infinite-horizon game. In each period a fair coin is flipped. If the coin comes up head, then Player 1 proposes a split of the money; if it comes up tails, then Player 2 proposes the split. After a proposal is made, the other player either accepts or rejects the proposal. If the proposal is accepted, then the money is immediately divided as proposed and payoffs are realized. If the proposal is rejected, then in the next period the above procedure is repeated, starting with a fresh flip of the coin. If an aggrement is never reached, none of them receives any money. Player 1's per-period discount factor is $\frac{2}{3}$ and Player 2's discount factor is $\frac{1}{3}$.

When solving the game, I assume that, if a proposal is rejected, Player 1 gets (discounted) present value of money $a$ and Player 2 gets present value of money $b$. Intuitively $a+b\leq1$ because money cannot grow by itself. But is there any way to argue $a+b\not>1$ using a recursive approach or using summation of series?

Comment: Please make it clear whether *value* means amount of money or utility. It is obvious that $a+b\le 1$ if free disposal holds and $a,b$ are monetary amounts. If $a,b$ are utilities, this may not be true: just assume $u_1(x) = x+1$ and $u_2(x) = x+ 2$.

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. _Value_ means monetary amounts. But I don't think it is obvious.

Comment: If the money available is 1, you split it giving $a$ to 1 and $b$ to 2. So $a+b \le 1$, assuming free disposal (they can toss some money away). As you wrote yourself, "money cannot grow by itself" and the game does not assume that bargainers can borrow money from the outside.

Comment: Yes, I already say that it is correct _intuitively_, but is there any way to argue it by something like infinite summation?